# Downloaded Ubuntu, no dual boot, can't access Windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, windows

I installed Ubuntu following the partition tutorial and everything seems fine except I seemed to have lost Windows. I can still see it in GParted, but there is no dual boot menu + I can't seem to get to it in any way.

I tried boot repair but no improvement. [Boot repair results](http://paste.ubuntu.com/12058573/).

My System: HP Envy Spectre 14, 4GB i5, 128SSD, F9 Boot Manager, F10 Bios

**Partition, File System, Mount, Label, Size, Used, Flags**

- `/dev/sda1`, ntfs, system reserved, 100MiB, 26.10MiB, Boot
- `/dev/sda2`, ntfs, 95.37GiB, 47.53GiB
- `/dev/sda4`, extended..20.99GiB..
- `/dev/sda5`, ext4, `/`, 18.99GiB, 4.61GiB
- `/dev/sda6`, linux-swap, 2.00GiB, 4.00KiB, diag
- unallocated, unallocated, 2.01GiB

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to let Grub know about Windows is `sudo update-grub`. This merely forces Grub to look at the hard disks and see what operating systems there are. Usually it will find Windows if it's there.

Comment: I would of course plus one but I'm not allowed. Did try that but it didn't work :/

Comment: I have no idea if this will help, but does your machine use UEFI?

Comment: I believe so. Not sure if that too was a constraint but hey ho, I figured it out posted the solution! Appreciate your help buddy!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone having similar trouble: I used *grub-customizer*

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

I kind of had an epiphany that maybe the problem wasn't the partitions or calls, but simply the grub screen. Of course big thanks to Stephen for playing that idea! Install the customizer and move your windows to the top!